# Apple Watch UDID incorrect

Tags: xcode

I have a really wierd issue with an Apple Watch UDID i copied from Xcode.

I paired the watch and went to the "Devices" window in Xcode. Here I got the UDID form the field "Identifier" under "Paired Watch Information".

When pasting into the dev portal I get "Please enter a valid Hardware UDID".

Is this not the correct UDID?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, it turns out theres a bug in the Devices window of Xcode.

If your Devices window is not wide enough to show the entire UDID of the Apple Watch, the remanining is just clipped and thus you are copying the visible part of the ID and not the full ID.

This shows the clipped identifier
[image: Clipped identifier]

Resizing the window shows the entire identifier.

[image: Full identifier]